# I want access the cart variables and perform addition of the quantity of each product php

Tags: php

I have cart which contains productid and productquantity, however i want to perform the addition of all the product quantity present in the cart and display it.

I have tried accessing variables of cart but was unable to do so.

```
array(1) {
  ["cart"]=>
  array(2) {
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(2)
    }
    [8]=>
    array(1) {
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

I want the addition of the quantity of the cart items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the sum of each quantity in your cart by

```
echo array_sum( array_column( $array['cart'], 'quantity' ) );
```

the output of above echo will be `3`.

Comment: @vanitya thanks that solved the issue. Would you please te;; mewWhere can i get detailed info on php array manipulation for studying?

Comment: Glad that is helps you! This answer may not be liked by you or may be heard from everywhere however, it's true that you should refer official php.net and keep busy with various operation on php using algorithms. You can find a lot of algorithms practice online. like codechef, Hackerrank etc...

Comment: @Vanitya it seems there is not other option then officail php.net for reference

Comment: There are but you will get great source only there.

Comment: if you wish to go free and start with something there are w3schools, tutorialspoint, geeksforgeek and my more those show you very little and brief list of functions together to overview.

Comment: but I personally refer php.net and practice.

Comment: @Vanitya Sure. Thanks